# getStaticPaths returning posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

getStaticPaths returning posts.map is not a function error while fetch slug in next.js with the following code.

```
  export async function getStaticPaths() {

  var config = {
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'API_ACCESS_KEY': 'hns2V0Ddbkkn8r1XLq3Kw7ZoiBTR0nmA',
 }
 } 
 const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/snippets';

const res = await fetch(url,config);
const posts = await res.json();
const paths = posts.map((post)=>{
return {
  params:{
    sid:post.id.toString(),
  }
}
});
return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(posts)` ?

Comment: Are you getting the expected output from the API request?